# Nodetool status shows java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I have a single node cassandra server. It has been working well for a long time until after a server restart I made yesterday.

Now `nodetool status` gives me the following error

```
error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Cassandra itself seems to be running. The subset of the logs:

```
...
INFO  03:58:18 Node /10.0.0.4 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  03:58:18 Waiting for gossip to settle before accepting client requests...
INFO  03:58:26 No gossip backlog; proceeding
```

Release version is 3.7

I haven't been able to crack this. I'd be very thankful for any help.

Let me know if I can provide any more useful information.

Comment: Can you give more info about ClassCastException? I had this exception which is related SSTable

Comment: It's not showing me any other information about the exception. Only that it's ClassCastException.

Comment: If you want more help you need to show the stacktrace. Because I assume you removed it and replaced with --StackTrace--

Comment: That's how nodetool returned it to me. There was no stack trace included.

Comment: The ClassCastException is in the server log or it's being thrown by nodetool?

Comment: @Horia It is being thrown by nodetool with `nodetool status` command.